# Paypal Express Checkout in-context in GWT, what to put in <form ... action=[?] ...>

Tags: java, gwt, paypal, express-checkout

In the [Paypal Checkout Experience in-context](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/) what I have to put in action? here:

```
<form id="myContainer" method="post" action=[?]></form>
```

"/checkout" doesn't work clearly! Thnaks!

Comment: To start the Express Checkout flow? Then it's your existing [`SetExpressCheckout` API call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) (server side), that obtains the ec token.

Comment: I have it, and I have also added the script to obtain the in-context functionality, but I don't know what to add in action...

Answer (score 2):

something like this maybe.

```
<form id="myContainer" method="post" action="/checkout"></form>

<script>
window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () { 
paypal.checkout.setup('9XKWYX3UHBPB2', {
    environment: 'sandbox',
    container: 'myContainer'
  }); 
};
</script>
<script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>


<form method='post' id="myContainer"><input type="text" name="CHARGE" value="1"/><input type="submit"/><form>
```

or

```
<form id="myContainer" action="paypal_ec_redirect.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value="10.00">    </input>
```

Comment: @anto150192 If it worked, please check my answer as the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: doesn't work, it's more complicated because it need to interact with the java code